# return type of round ()

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following piece of code:

```
a_round = round (3.5)   # First use of a_round
a_round = 4.5   # Incompatible types, since a_round is regarded as an int
```

It turns out that the return value of round () is regarded as an int.
That this is so, I conclude because at the second statement, mypy complains:

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float",variable has type "int")
```

I am using Python 3.5, so it should be a float. What am I missing. Should I somehow hint mypy about the Python version? How exactly?

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem/error that you see? Rather than an "it seems" statement.

Comment: not sure what your question is here as you're binding a reference to your new scalar which is of different type here sp `a_round` becomes float after the second line

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: I've edited my question

Comment: You need to post your [MCVE] bro

Comment: @EdChum: The question is why mypy complains about the second statement, since the first statement should have made a_round a float, not an int.

Comment: If you want static type checking, and you want `a_round` to be a float, you could put `a_round = float(round(3.5))`

Comment: @Lightness: These two lines of code are my MCV example. They are all that's needed to reproduce, the whole program so to say...

Comment: interresting that so many people develop with python but just a few of them know how to check/test/investigate things with the console, which is even faster than writing a question on SO and waiting for answeres. Sorry but typing a `type(round(3.5))` in your cmd/shell shouldn't be such a big problem...

Comment: @khelwood: I know how to work around it. It just doesn't seem correct. If I e.g. use math.sin rather than round, there's no problem. But round should be the same thing: a function taking a float and returning a float. What am I missing?

Comment: What makes you say that round _should_ return a float? `sin` is a completely different situation.

Comment: The documentation of CPython 3.5 states: round(number[, ndigits])
Return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: OK Guys, I  should have read on: Return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input. Delegates to number.__round__(ndigits). SORRY AND THANKS! (And I wouldn't have dreamt of making it like that...)

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I know how to use the console, but I was convinced I'd read the docs properly, which wasn't the case!

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: [Really?](https://ideone.com/FVNET1) Neither an error, nor output!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- right, but that isn't using mypy. OP isn't asking why Python behaves in a certain way, he's asking why mypy is reporting a particular error. So, to repro and see the output OP is reporting, you'd need to run `mypy test.py`, not `python test.py`.

Comment: @Michael0x2a: Oh, right. Wasn't really clear to me that this is a question about output from MyPy, but that could just be because I don't really use it and so didn't grok that intuitively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fully clarify:

```
type (round (3.5, 0)) # <class 'float'>
type (round (3.5)) # <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Good idea to clarify, that's the most readable answer here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your implementation:

```
>>> round(3.5)
4
>>> type(round(3.5))
<class 'int'>
>>> round(3.5,1)
3.5
>>> type(round(3.5,1))
<class 'float'>
```

Of course it is trivial to create a float in all cases:

```
>>> float(round(3.5))
4.0
>>> type(float(round(3.5)))
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine this script:

```
a_round = round(3.5)   # First use of a_round
print(a_round.__class__)
a_round = 4.5   # Incompatible types, since a_round is regarded as an int
print(a_round.__class__)
```

On python 2.7 the result is:

```
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
```

But with python 3.5 will be:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
```

Solution: You should cast explicitly to float when using python 3.5:

```
a_round = float(round(3.5))
```